# SSL certificate error on Google Chrome , IE

Tags: ssl

My wordpress website has ssl certificate properly installed and I verified it at digicert and other ssl verification websites. The website works fine on firefox browser however on the Chrome and IE, it tends to give Invalid Certificate error.

Can someone tell my why and provide a solution?

Thanks

Comment: What is your website? What error do you get?

Comment: www.scienceinvesting.com and the error i get is certificate is invalid

Comment: Ok, the certificate is valid. This could be due to those browsers caching the website/certificate/whatever. Did you try restarting the computer? Anyway, this is not related to WordPress but your computer/browsers, so sadly we can't help you here